# Error saying that function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Console logs keep saying that the function is not defined onClick of this button. I really can't find out why. I have 2 other popups that use this same format, all of them say function undefined when I push each button for each popup. The page doesn't state that there any any obvious javascript syntax errors.

Thanks for any help

HTML

```
<div class="popup" id="popup-subscribe">
   <div id="close-subscribe" class="close-button"> </div>
   <div class="popup-title">Subscribe</div>
   <form method="post" name="subscribe" action="">
      <span class="label" style="margin-right: 5px">Name: </span><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" /><br>
      <span class="label" style="margin-right: 5px">Email: </span><input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email_subscribe" /><br>
      <div class="errors" id="subscribe-errors"></div>
      <div onclick="validateSubscribeForm()" class="button-medium">Sign me up!</div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function validateSubscribeForm() {
var emailSubscribe =document.forms["subscribe"]["email_subscribe"].value;
var atpos=emailSubscribe.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=emailSubscribe.lastIndexOf(".");
var name = document.forms["subscribe"]["name"].value;
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=emailSubscribe.length)
  {
  $("#subscribe-errors").html("The email you entered is not valid");
  return false;
  } 
  else if (name == null || name == "") 
  {
  $("#subscribe-errors").html("Please enter a name");
  }else {
  document.subscribe.submit();
  }
}
```

Specifically, the console log error states: Uncaught ReferenceError: validateSubscribeForm is not defined

Comment: `$` jQuery included ?? either use ready() or wrap it in an anonymous function

Comment: It's included at the top of the page by a PHP include();

Comment: ur defining it the script inline or separate js file? have you included it on page?

Comment: I included this on the page. After the body.

Comment: @Josh: Is this *all* of your code? Is this function inside of a `$(document).ready()` callback?

Comment: @Josh put it in the head not after the body

Comment: try putting it before the html. in the head or at the top of the body tag before declaring the html.

Comment: Thanks guys. That was the issue. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your JavaScript function definition in the `head` tag of your HTML:

```
<head>
    <!-- INCLUDE jQuery library first -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateSubscribeForm() {
            var emailSubscribe = document.forms["subscribe"]["email_subscribe"].value;
            var atpos = emailSubscribe.indexOf("@");
            var dotpos = emailSubscribe.lastIndexOf(".");
            var name = document.forms["subscribe"]["name"].value;
            if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= emailSubscribe.length) {
                $("#subscribe-errors").html("The email you entered is not valid");
                return false;
            } else if (name == null || name == "") {
                $("#subscribe-errors").html("Please enter a name");
            } else {
                document.subscribe.submit();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="popup" id="popup-subscribe">
        <div id="close-subscribe" class="close-button"></div>
        <div class="popup-title">Subscribe</div>
        <form method="post" name="subscribe" action=""> <span class="label" style="margin-right: 5px">Name: </span>

            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" />
            <br /> <span class="label" style="margin-right: 5px">Email: </span>

            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email_subscribe" />
            <br />
            <div class="errors" id="subscribe-errors"></div>
            <div onclick="validateSubscribeForm()" class="button-medium">Sign me up!</div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. Do you have any ideas as to why this would happen now? I've had all the scripts on the bottom of the page before but now it just started messing up. The only thing I can think of that I changed recently was the version of jQuery being used. And the jQuery library is being included with PHP. I always thought it was better to leave the scipts at the bottom of the page too.

Comment: JavaScript functions need to be declared first before they can be called (like so many other languages) @Josh .

Answer (score 1):

Your missed Jquery here. Include Jquery library.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```